# Como fazer echo de PHP para Ajax? Sistema de Login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou a trabalhar num sistema de login em que avisa o usuário, se o username já existe na base de dados. Basicamente tenho uma janela popup na mesma página onde estão os campos de input tanto para login como para registro do usuário. A ideia era submeter os campos e retornar um parágrafo que iria informar o usuário se a conta tinha sido adicionada com sucesso ou não.

Aqui está o código:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitlogin'])) {

        global $connection;
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($_POST['username']));
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($_POST['password']));

        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

            /*Register*/
                if(isset($_POST['classmember'])){
                    $class_member= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($_POST['classmember']));

                    $query = "SELECT member FROM members WHERE member='$username';";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if($password == GUILDPASS) {
                         if($num_rows == 0) {

                         $query2 = "INSERT INTO members(member,pass,class_id,status_id) VALUES ('$username',". '\''. GUILDPASS . '\'' . ",$class_member,3);";

                         $insert = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);

                         echo "Added Successfully";

                         } else {
                             echo "player already exists";
                         }
                     } else {
                         echo "Wrong password";
                     }
                }        
            /* LOGIN*/

                else {    
                    $query = "SELECT member,pass FROM members WHERE member='$username' AND pass='$password';";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                    if($num_rows == 0) {
                         echo "Create Account or Username/Password incorrect..";   
                    } else if ($num_rows == 1){
                         $_SESSION['sessionid'] = session_id();
                    }
                }


        } else {
            echo "Password/Username missing";
        }
     header("Location: ../index.php");
     exit();
}
```

Comment: Amigo, você recebe algum erro quando executa esse código? Tome muito cuidado ao utilizar "SELECT member FROM members WHERE member='$username';", pois isso abre as portas para SQL Injection. Nunca use uma variável diretamente na consulta sql, sem filtrar.

Comment: Não é possivel realizar echo por ajax devido a página já ter sido carregada. Uma alternativa seria coletar o retorno da requisição ajax, e manipular o DOM da página para simular um "Echo". Notas que o PHP significa (Hypertext Preprocessor) ou seja, algo que manipula o texto, antes dele ser renderizado.

Comment: @Stéfano De momento esta em producao mais tarde irei passar  tudo para prepared statements e rever a segurança do código.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar o valor retornado e utilizar no ajax, exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'SUA URL',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){
     alert(data)
  }
});
```

O data é o echo que você retornou do PHP, o exemplo acima, está usando o dataType como `html`, mas normalmente utilizamos como `json` e retornamos o `json` do PHP com `json_encode()`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Infelizmente já tentei fazer isso, e o que acontece no meu caso, é que quando faço console.log(data) o que aparece é o HTML inteiro da página. Já tentei até nao fazer por ajax, e apenas submeter os POST para a mesma página mas por alguma razao quando deixo a form action="" ele retorna para o folder anterior e vai para o dashboard do XAMPP

Comment: No seu arquivo, ele só tem o codigo PHP, ou você esta usando o PHP e HTML no mesmo codigo?